# How to use a GUI generated window with command line terminal in background?

Tags: c++, opengl, ncurses

Here is the main file of the game snake I am developing. It uses OpenGL and ncurses. Everything runs exactly like I want it too, but I can only input my key presses to play the game if my command line terminal is the top level process of my computer. Currently, when I run the program, the OpenGL window spawns ontop of my command line prompt and then I need to re select my command line prompt and bring it to the front to play my game.

I want my terminal to recognize my key presses when the terminal is behind the openGL window. How do I do this if it is possible? I am using Ubuntu Linux.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <ncurses.h>

#include "Snake.h"
#include <GL/glut.h>

int khbit(void)
{
    int ch = getch();

    if (ch != ERR)
    {
        ungetch(ch);
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;   
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::unique_ptr<GameBoxes::Box> squareBackground(new GameBoxes::Box(std::stoi(argv[1]), std::stoi(argv[2]),
                               std::stoi(argv[3]), std::stoi(argv[4])));

    int cArgs[4];
    (*squareBackground).getSizeArray(cArgs);


    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    (*squareBackground).createBackGroundTexture();

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); //new

    // initialize random seed:
    srand (time(NULL));

    // start ncurses
    initscr();
    // Line buffering disabled
    cbreak();
    // Don't echo while we do getch
    noecho();
    // Allows checking for Keypress
    nodelay(stdscr, TRUE);
    scrollok(stdscr, TRUE);

    bool play = true;
    while (play == true)
    {
        bool alive = true;
        std::unique_ptr<GameBoxes::Snake> snake(new GameBoxes::Snake(*squareBackground, cArgs)); //new

        int direction;
        char directionTwo = 't';

        flushinp();

        while (alive == true)
        {
            if (khbit())
            {
                direction = getch();
                directionTwo = direction;
                alive = (*snake).moveSnake(*squareBackground, direction, cArgs); // Grow into a loop
                flushinp();
            }
            else
            {
                alive = (*snake).moveSnake(*squareBackground, directionTwo, cArgs); // Grow into a loop
            }

            if (direction == 'k')
            {
                endwin();
                return 0;
            }

            std::chrono::milliseconds dura( 40);
            std::this_thread::sleep_for( dura );

        }

    }

    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is possible with most window managers (not sure is Unity capable enough; OpenBox definitely is), but is that what you really need? Wouldn’t it be better to read key presses directly from OpenGL window instead, not relying on a terminal at all?

Comment: I'll need to figure out how to do that. Thanks for letting me know it is possible.

Comment: You did know that’s possible as no program on your desktop relies on a terminal =) But not well that keyboard handling is part of GLUT (OpenGL utility/loader/helper) and **not** OpenGL itself.